# Whats the right method for different colour/style in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to have 2 different colours/styles for each word of my website name, something like this:

[image: sample]

I currently use:

```
<a href="#">James<strong>.</strong><span>Wood</span></a>
```

("STRONG" and "SPAN" tags inside "A" tag).

And then do the rest with CSS.

Is this the right method to do it with CSS if we can't use images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That html code is not readable. It's right to do it with css but in a way like this:

```
<a href="#" class="f18 b">
<span class="green uc">james</span>.<span class="orange uc">wood</span>
</a>
```

and define css classes:

```
.f18 {font-size: 18px;}
.b   {font-weight:bold;}
.uc  {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: It might be cleaner to add your `.f18` and `.b` classes to the `<a>` rather than adding an extra div into the mix.

Comment: nice suggestion, applied :)

Comment: thanks, what about the . (dot) style, should i use another span or strong would do it?

Comment: You're probably best to style the entire `<a>` with bold, uppercase, red, 18pt font and then just change the 2 spans inside to green and orange.

Comment: I've added some sample code in another response below, just to compare... it's basically the same, just a little neater (in my opinion)

Comment: So much presentation in your class names.  Have fun renaming those when the color scheme is blue and yellow and the text should all be small caps in a 12px font.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to Gianps answer, but with a bit simpler CSS:

Working Demo:
http://www.cdpn.io/wvCou

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" class='title'><span class='green'>James</span>.<span class='orange'>Wood</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.title .green {color: green;}
.title .orange {color: orange;}
```